# a git branch fetching changes from an untracked branch

Tags: git, github

for my repo `git branch -vv` returns the follwing

```
  dev  5eed80e [origin/dev: behind 1] Create NeweestFileBaby
  dev2 9a50723 commiting first1 change
* main 8898177 [origin/main] Create NewDev
```

So  I am checked out at my local `main` branch

Then I make a change in my *remote `dev` branch* in github, then for an experiment i do

`git fetch`

at this point I am not expecting to fetch changes from remote `dev` since my local `main` branch is set to track changes from remote `main` but for some reaseon it does fetch the changes from remote `dev`, again I m checked out at local `main`.
could you please tell me why does this happen?

this is interesting because with `git push` the logic kind of works corretcly because I am able to push cahnges only to my respective tracking branches from respective local branches that are set upstream to respective remote branches.

Comment: A simple `git fetch` will fetch all the branches from remote. So it should update  `origin/main` as well as `origin/dev`, just like you're seeing.

Comment: @joanis "*fetch all the branches from remote*" From **the remote**; the remote (if there're many) is calculated from the currently checked out branch — it's the upstream remote for the branch. If there is no upstream remote for the current branch — `origin` is used. `git fetch --all` fetches all configured refspecs from all remotes. Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: @phd agreed, those details are a lot more precise than what I said, but I wanted to provide OP with what happens in the most common case, which already surprised them given this question.

Comment: @joanis Let me use this wording: A bare `git fetch` fetches **all branches** from the remote. PS. Yes, I'm a nerd, pedant and a wet blanket, sorry.

Comment: @phd I can't blame you, I'm a nerd and a pendant in my own ways. We just get triggered on different things. Lol.

Comment: @phd I'm not being quite honest, I'm a nerd and I can be really nitpicky, but I can also be sloppy sometimes, so it's a reach for me to claim I'm a pedant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a side note: "Untracked branch" is the wrong phrase here.

Git's terminology is not good, because:

- the verb *track* applies to files: some file is either *tracked* or *untracked*, based on whether that file appears in Git's index at this very moment; but
- the verb *track* applies to branch names, in that a branch *`B`* that has an *upstream* setting of *`U`* is said to *track* *`U`*.

These two notions are completely different.  The first one means that the tracked file will be in the *next commit* (if it's still tracked at that time), while the second one means that `git status` will report on different commits reachable from *`B`* and *`U`* and that `git merge` or `git rebase` with no additional arguments will use *`U`* if *`B`* is the current branch.

We're familiar with this problem in other cases: for instance, the word [*set*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set), even when treated as just a noun or just a verb ("set a place at the table"), has many meanings; it has another set when treated as an adjective.  But at least with Git there was, once, some hope that we might not have to deal with this kind of craziness.  If the upstream of a branch were only ever referred to as "upstream", we wouldn't need an extra meaning for *track*.  But almost 20 years down the line, we still have both terms.  (And, of course, the word *upstream* is a bit problematic as well, but let's not go there now.)

But there are two big asymmetries between `git fetch` and `git push` here:

> This is interesting because with `git push` the logic kind of works correctly because I am able to push changes only to my respective tracking branches from respective local branches that are set upstream to respective remote branches.

Technically, you push *commits* (not changes as commits are snapshots plus metadata), but yes: `git push`, with no extra arguments, tells Git to:

1. figure out which branch you're "on" right now (as in `git status` says `on branch main` or whatever);
2. use the upstream setting of this branch to determine a *remote* (e.g., `origin`) and a branch name on that remote; and
3. in effect, run `git push remote branch`, assuming a `push.default` setting of `simple` or `current`.

Note that with `push.default` set to `upstream`, the effect here is `git push remote branch:reverse-map-of-upstream` instead, i.e., the branch can have a *different* name on the remote, but with `simple` and `current`, the push goes to the *same* name on the remote.  With `push.default` set to `matching`, the behavior here is that from Git version 1: the equivalent of `git push remote :`, which has not been found to be very useful but is preserved for backwards compatibility.

With `git fetch`, however, the default still uses step 1 and *half* of step 2: Git will figure out the correct remote from the current branch (or use a hardcoded fallback, `origin`, if this fails).  But after that point, Git uses the `remote.remote.fetch` setting(s) (this is a multivalued configuration setting, so there can be more than one entry listed).  These provide the refspec argument(s), which above—for `git push`—were a single branch name or a colon-separated pair of branch names for the two recommended values (`matching` being the non-recommended one, and `nothing` causing the `git push` to fail).

The *default* here for `origin`, if you have not set it, is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note the two "glob-like" asterisk `*` characters here.  This refspec means *match all branch names on the remote, and copy each one to a remote-tracking name locally*.  So we `git fetch` *all* the new commits from `origin`, bringing *all* of them into our local repository, and then we update *all* our remote-tracking `refs/remotes/origin/whatever` names.

The effect is that `git fetch` means *fetch all branches from `origin`*, which is just what you saw.  The updates of the remote-tracking names are implied by the refspec `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` (with the leading `+` setting the "force" flag, so that each name is updated even if the operation is not a fast-forward one).

Note that running:

```
git fetch origin main
```

will limit the `git fetch` operation so that, in spite of however many branch names the Git software at the `origin` URL lists, we bring over only those new commits needed to update our `origin/main` remote-tracking name.  Our Git software adds those new-to-us commits to our object database.  Curiously, despite the lack of a colon and `refs/remotes/origin/main`—we didn't run `git fetch origin main:refs/remotes/origin/main`—our Git now goes ahead and updates our `origin/main`.  But why?

The answer lies in that same backwards compatibility issue that plagues `git push` so that `matching` means `git push` with a colon refspec.  Without going into all the boring history here, let's just note that `git fetch` now (since Git 1.8.2) "opportunistically updates" remote-tracking names as configured in the `remote.remote.fetch` line(s), whether or not you give a specific refspec.

The bottom line here is that:

```
git fetch origin
```

fetches *all configured fetch branches* from `origin`, and "all configured fetch branches" defaults to "all branches".  There is a `--all` flag for `git fetch`, but it means *all remotes:* it has no effect on which *branches* are to be fetched.  Then, too, there's the terminology issue: we don't actually fetch *branches*.  We fetch *commits*.  We just *find the commits to fetch* using names, which may be branch names.  These are *branch names as seen on the remote*.  The commits come into our own local Git-objects-database, and then Git updates—or doesn't update—*remote-tracking names* as specified via the refspec arguments.

#### Unnumbered footnotes

A *refspec* is, in effect, a pair of names separated by a colon `:`, and optionally prefixed with a plus sign `+`.  The names can be branch or tag names (abbreviated) or fully spelled out, e.g., `refs/heads/main` or `refs/tags/v1.2`.  Doing the full spelling-out is wise in any automated code since Git's attempt to match a partial name to a full name may yield surprises.  The name on the left side of the colon is the *source*, which for `git push` is local and for `git fetch` is remote.  The name on the right side of the colon is the *destination*, which for `git push` is remote and for `git fetch` is local.  The plus sign, as noted above, sets the `--force` flag for that particular ref.  Refspecs may use glob `*` in a limited fashion; the `*` must appear on both sides.  The limits on `*` matching were improved at some point to allow, e.g., `+refs/heads/pr-*:refs/remotes/pr-*` if you like; before that `*` had to match "whole component" parts (i.e., just before or after a slash).

What I call *remote-tracking names* (`origin/main` or, fully spelled out, `refs/remotes/origin/main`), modern Git documentation calls *remote-tracking branch names*.  These are not branch names because branch names start with `refs/heads/`.

For fetching from multiple remotes, I recommend using `git remote update` rather than `git fetch`.  This is partly because ancient Git required it, but I think overall that code has been better-maintained.